# onCreate runs 2 times with singletop launch mode set

Tags: java, android, android-activity, oncreate

**Problem:**

My Launching Activity creatively named `LoadingActivity`'s [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method is called 2 times.

**Manifest Content:**

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        ...
        <activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name="com.awesome.app.activites.LoadingActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

First [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) call is called with `Bundle savedInstanceState` which is `null`, shortly after which the [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) method is called again, but this time with Bundle savedInstanceState which contains the following serialized content:

```
Bundle[{com.google.app_measurement.screen_service=Bundle[{referrer_name=LoadingActivity, id=1612091517631091562, name=null}], android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[{android:views={16908290=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@a24446f, 2131296302=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@a24446f, 2131296313=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@a24446f, 2131296424=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@a24446f, 2131296445=android.widget.ProgressBar$SavedState@b25257c, 2131296581=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@a24446f, 2131296582=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@a24446f}}], androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key=Bundle[{}], android:lastAutofillId=1073741823, android:fragments=android.app.FragmentManagerState@a24ee05}]
```

*Yes, this doesn't mean much, but it may be related to something at the bottom of the post.*

**Tried:**

I have tried setting [launchmode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode) settings with `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for the `LoadingActivty` in my `AndroidManifest.xml`, but this does not help at all, it still runs the [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) 2 times.

I have gone through my onCreate method, no where do I onCreate again or change ApplicationContext settings i.e. Orientation (physically or programmatically), etc.

**Any idea why this happens and what I can do to resolve it.**

For what it is worth, I have recently updated my deps and see this in my Manifest:

[image]

*It compiles (change the package name for obv reasons) with the portrait launchmode, but I think this may have something to do with the double launch*